# Why does memtest keep saying I have RAM running at 0Hz?

Tags: memory, bios, memtest86+

So I have been running into problems with my computer rebooting ever twenty to five minutes, this was really annoying me so I decided to run memtest+ on it. Unfortunately, when I boot up the memtest, it's not detecting the speed, which is really infuriating me as I am unable to determine if my RAM is good. I have run apt-get install to get the latest memtest, so what am I missing? Could this mis-configuration be what is causing my spontaneous reboots?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: If it can't read the speed it's going to have default somehow--and if that default doesn't match what your memory wants that could easily cause a reboot even if the memory is actually functional.

Comment: Oh, could you elaborate on that point? The motherboard supports two sticks of RAM, but only one is currently installed.